# Can't see why this won't work | Loop won't run

Tags: java, for-loop

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner xis = new Scanner(System.in);
    int H1 = 0;
    int M1 = 0;
    int H2 = 0;
    int M2 = 0;
    int[] numeros = new int[4];
    System.out.println("Type the numbers.");
    for(int i = 0; i <= numeros.length; i++)
    {
        numeros[i] = xis.nextInt();
        H1 = H1 + numeros[0];
        M1 = M1 + numeros[1];
        H2 = H2 + numeros[2];
        M2 = M2 + numeros[3];
    }
    System.out.println(H1);
    System.out.println(H2);
    int horaDuracao = (H2 - H1) * -1;
    int minutoDuracao = (M2 - M1) * -1;
    if(horaDuracao <= 0)
    {
        horaDuracao = horaDuracao + 24;
    }
    if (minutoDuracao <= 0)
    {
        minutoDuracao = minutoDuracao + 59;
        horaDuracao = horaDuracao + -1;
    }
}
```

When the user types the answer to this: 
System.out.println("Type the numbers.");

It won't continue to the next part of my code.

Sorry if it's a repost, but I kept searching for some time for something like this, but couldn't find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop goes for 5 iterations, not 4. You should remove the = from the terminating clause in order to get it working.
`for(int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++)`

Comment: Thanks, still learning how to code, am having those little problems far more frequently than I'd like..