# About requesting users to enter arbitrary times of input and switching values in the array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to code a method `throwAgain(int[] dice)`. I was told to switch the values in the dice[] (the dice has only 5 indexes) and the values in the specified index (it means which die) the user asked to changed needed to swap with random number ranged from 1 to 6.

`rollDie()` is the function that generates the six numbers. Note: anything else other than integer 1 to 6  and two same integers are invalid inputs.

I could not figure how to code the part that the users can enter up to 4 inputs. I do not know how to terminate the Scanner say after one or two or three or four inputs are entered. In addition, I do not think the way I code the program to determine what input it is could help me to swap the numbers in the array.

Reference Sample:

```
Original array dice[]= 6 3 2 5 5
("List which die to throw again: 3 6") 
invalid input!
("List which die to throw again: 3 3")
invalid input!
("List which die to throw again: 3 4") 
output: 6 3 5 3 5
```

---

```
public static void throwAgain(int[] dice){
     Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print("List which die to throw again: ");
     String a= new String("");String b= new String("");
     String c= new String("");String d= new String("");
     a= input.next();b= input.next();c= input.next();
     d= input.next();

     if (a.equals("1")||b.equals("1")||c.equals("1")||d.equals("1")){
         dice[0]=rollDie();
     }else if (a.equals("2")||b.equals("2")||c.equals("2")||d.equals("2")){
         dice[1]=rollDie();
     }else if (a.equals("3")||b.equals("3")||c.equals("3")||d.equals("3")){
         dice[2]=rollDie();
     }else if (a.equals("4")||b.equals("4")||c.equals("4")||d.equals("4")){
         dice[3]=rollDie();
     }else if (a.equals("5")||b.equals("5")||c.equals("5")||d.equals("5")){
         dice[4]=rollDie();
     }
}
```

This is my edited methods: 
         Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.print("List which die to throw again: ");

```
      while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String theLine = input.nextLine();
            String[] split = theLine.split(" ");
            /*for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(split[i]);
                // Do something with each entry
            }*/
          for(int i=0; i<=split.length-1;i++){
            System.out.print(split[i]);
            if (split[i].equals("1")){
                 dice[0]=rollDie();
             }else if (split[i].equals("2")){
                 dice[1]=rollDie();
             }else if (split[i].equals("3")){
                 dice[2]=rollDie();
             }else if (split[i].equals("4")){
                 dice[3]=rollDie();
             }else if (split[i].equals("5")){
                 dice[4]=rollDie();
             }
          }
        }
        System.out.println(dice);
}
```

The result is the same as the input. I just could not figure out what errors it has. And also I wanted to use a for loop to limit up to four times of input. I do not if it is a good idea. I tried to do it that way, but it always executed four times. I wanted it to stop whenever the user hit the enter key whether he only enters one input or two input or more but less than four.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Can't see why this won't work | Loop won't run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29639110/cant-see-why-this-wont-work-loop-wont-run/29639220#29639220) 
Check out this SO question, it has the code format you would want in order to end the scanner after a certain amount of iterations.  All you really need is a for loop.  Be sure to structure the for loop correctly! 

If you want to use the scanner input to swap die positions, I would recommend using .split() and break the input up using spaces as a delimiter (" ").  Thus, when you have the input "3 4", split will make an array that is [ 3, 4 ] and you can manipulate your dice array accordingly with those numbers.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner theScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print('List which die to throw again: ');
    while (theScanner.hasNextLine()) {

        String theLine = theScanner.nextLine();
        String[] split = theLine.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(split[i]);
            // Do something with each entry
        }

        System.out.print("List which die to throw again: ");
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't know if the following codes is what you meant. I do not if I comprehend your answer correctly. A for loop will keep requesting the user to enter a number amount of inputs until the specified times. I want the program to keep running as soon as the user hit enter after he finishes entering one or two or three or four inputs.                                  Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
   
  System.out.print("List which die to throw again: ");
  int Sp[]= new int[4];
   for(int i=0;i<Sp.length;i++){
    Sp[i]=input.nextInt();
     
   }
  System.out.print(Sp[1]);

Comment: `while ( theScanner.hasNextLine() ) {
      System.out.print("List which die to throw again: "); String theLine = theScanner.nextLine(); // String[] split = theLine.split(" "); // do something with the array
`}

Comment: I posted the edited code on the edited question section. I still could not figure out a good way of doing it. The codes had been written right below the previous one. Appreciate it!